# Does replaying missions on a lower difficulty still give me the relics?

Tags: starcraft-2

Can I replay a mission on a lower difficulty to still get the Protoss or Zerg relics?

Answer (score 5):

The relics don't depend on the difficulty level, so, if it's too hard to get them you can lower difficulty.

However, if you play for achievements you must complete it on the asked difficulty level...

Comment: thanks, what about other secondary objectives, like killing all spectres which award 5000 credits each?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the relics at any level, but yes, you can only get achievements on normal and hard.

*HOWEVER* if you run the mission for the achievement, and don't get all the relics, you can replay it on easy, and get the relics, and the relics will then transfer to the next mission in the campaign. Or if you've already run it on easy, and you want to re-run it on hard or brutal for the achievement, you **DO NOT** have to grab all the relics...If you've gotten them all one time, then you get them for the rest of the campaign, regardless of any mission replays you may do.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest: instead of playing that on easier difficulty level, try to Google for how to accomplish this mission on 'hard/brutal' level... This is possible from Bronze players, it doesn't required A LOT of skills.